# jquery ajax post within a function not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

So i have created a function to post data to a php page:

```
function updateData(x,y){
     $.ajax({   
        type: 'POST',   
        url: 'myupdate.php',   
        data: {x:y},
           success: function(data){
           $("#resultdiv").html(data);
          }
       });
}
```

And I call the function like this:

```
$(".myclass").click(function(){
        var newname = $("#myname").val();    //value of input type="text".
        updateData('name', newname);        // also tried updateData(name, newname)
});
```

So if i input the value as Rocky and initiate the function, problem is that the value sent to the php page `myupdate.php` is x=Rocky. I want it to be name=Rocky. How can i solve this.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use bracket notation when providing the key of an object in a variable. Try this:

```
function updateData(x, y) {
    var data = {};
    data[x] = y;

    $.ajax({   
        type: 'POST',   
        url: 'myupdate.php',   
        data: data,
        success: function(data){
            $("#resultdiv").html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to define object property dynamically

```
function updateData(x,y){
     var post_data= {};
     post_data[x]=y; // dynamic property
     $.ajax({   
        type: 'POST',   
        url: 'myupdate.php',   
        data: post_data,
           success: function(data){
           $("#resultdiv").html(data);
          }
       });
}
```